# TResponse must be a non abstract type with a parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter TResponse

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to create a function like

```
        public static TResponse Run<TService, TResponse>(Controller mvcController,            IServiceController serviceController, Func<TService, TResponse> action, bool suppressErrors)
        where TService : ICommunicationObject
        where TResponse : ResponseBase<TResponse>
    {
        TResponse response = serviceController.Run<TService, TResponse>(action);
        if (!suppressErrors)
            response.Result.Errors.ToList().ForEach(i => mvcController.ModelState.AddModelError(UniqueKey.ValidationMessage, i.Message));
        return response;
    }
```

and class has been defined as

```
[DataContract]
public class ResponseBase<T> where T: new()
{
    public ResponseBase()
    {
        Result = new Result<T>();
    }

    [DataMember]
    public Result<T> Result { get; set; }
}
```

I am getting the compilation error as TResponse must be a non abstract type with a parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter TResponse

Any help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although you've defined the `new()` constraint for `T` in `ResponseBase<T>`, the compiler requires you to declare the same constraint in other classes that use `ResponseBase<T>` generically.

All you have to do is add the `new()` constraint to `TResponse` in your method:

```
public static TResponse Run<TService, TResponse>(Controller mvcController, IServiceController serviceController, Func<TService, TResponse> action, bool suppressErrors)
    where TService : ICommunicationObject
    where TResponse : ResponseBase<TResponse>, new()
```

Comment: As to the reason why this is happening is because you have defined `<T>` for `ResponseBase<T>` to restrict `T` to be of type `new()` which means that any object that you pass in as `T` will need to have this restriction.

Comment: This works, thank you. I'd like to understand in greater detail, why the compiler requires the `new()` constraint?